# Realtime i18n Vuejs doesn't refresh text in dropdown

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-i18n

I need immediate update when I change language by i18n in select

html

```
<base-dropdown-item
        v-for="(f, i) in filters"
        :key="`dropdown-${i}`"
        @click="filter = f"
        >{{ f.label }}</base-dropdown-item
```

typescript

```
data() {
return {
  q: '',
  filter: { label: this.$t('myTasks.filter.Incomplete'), value: 2 },
  filters: [
    { label: this.$t('myTasks.filter.Incomplete'), value: 2 },
    { label: this.$t('myTasks.filter.done'), value: 3 },
    { label: this.$t('myTasks.filter.all'), value: 1 }
  ],

  qTasks: []
};
},
watch: {
'filter.value'() {
  this.$emit('filter', this.filter);
},
};
```

I need to change language real time
when i need to refresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Language won't change because you are defining the labels inside the data. Try moving it to a computed property.

```js
    computed: {
      filters() {
        return [
          { label: this.$t('myTasks.filter.Incomplete'), value: 2 },
          { label: this.$t('myTasks.filter.done'), value: 3 },
          { label: this.$t('myTasks.filter.all'), value: 1 }
        ];
      },
    },
```

Once you move it to a computed prop the value of the labels should change accordingly to the language

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to change the locale in the example.

Maybe the [documentation](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/locale.html) helps you. I am not sure if you set the locale messages right. You can use `$i18n.locale` to change the locale locally inside the component or `$root.$i18n.locale` to change it globally in your app.